Javascript library to format coordinate conversions
I'm new to coordinate conversions. I'm working with angular and needed to convert lat/long coordinates to multiple coordinate formats. I'm looking for a library that can aid in coordinate transformations and formatting.
I tried proj4js however we have to manually format the strings especially for utm (have to calculate the zone number and zone letter manually). Is there a library that will do both and same time support multiple formats such as lat/long to utm, mgrs, bng and igr? (looking to support more if needed)
Or if i use proj4js for transformation is there any other library that can be used for formatting?
I tried proj4js for transforming coordinates however had to manually format the coordinate strings. I'm not sure if proj4js covers all special cases for each format as well.
